# Row Level Security (RLS) in Power BI with multiple roles does not work anymore - no change made actually

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, row-level-security

I have a Power BI report that I publish as an app to several people.
Let's assume, the report has a table "Reps" and a table "Customers".

The "rep table" has the following interesting columns:

- Rep Name
- Rep Nr
- Region

The "Customer table" has the following interesting columns:

- Rep Nr
- Customer Nr
- Customer Name

The "Rep Nr" is the join key, while it is a many to many (m:n) relationship, where the direction is "rep" filters "customer".
With RLS, I created different roles.  For example:

- Region 1: [REGION_CODE] = "1"
- Region 2: [REGION_CODE] = "2"
- Rep: [Rep User Principal] = userprincipalname()

The setting is, that I advise a complete (email/user) distribution list to the role Rep by default. In this role, everyone is included, and each rep sees only his customers.
In the role region 1 are some people included, that can see not only his customers, but all customers of this region.

This worked perfectly fine for more than a year. It was never a problem to assign a user to several roles. However, since approximately mid of Cecember 2021, it does not work anymore. I did not change anything. People who are assigned to n roles, cannot see any data.

The message I get in Power BI Desktop:

> **Couldn't load the data for this visual.**
> The user belongs to multiple roles 'Region 1, Rep' that have security filters, which isn't supported when one of the roles has filters affecting table 'Customers' with SecurityFilteringBehavior=Both relationships.

Does anyone know if Microsoft/Power BI changed anything that explaines this behavior?
Does anyone know if I can easily change it to the old setting?

Comment: Rather than trying to puzzle out how to revert to an earlier state (which, even if it were possible, is unlikely to remain possible going forward), it seems better to redesign things so this restriction isn't hit. The current model is strange: why is what regions a customer belongs to defined by their representatives? Does that mean they can suddenly change regions of different representatives are assigned? It seems more likely this should be an intrinsic property of the customer (even if it's decided it should be derived from the representatives).

Comment: Well, it is more vice versa. Each rep is assigned to a region. When a customer is aquired, the customer is assigned to the closest rep and therefore assigned to a region through its rep. For me it is totally strange since it worked for so long and without any changes it doesn't.

Comment: Whenever anyone says "It wasn't anything we changed" it's always suspect, of course. :P In my experience it rarely pays off to focus on what changed if it is a near certainty it can't be changed back, so you should instead focus on moving forward. Both RLS + multiple roles and bidi relationships are not favored; the combination will be even less so. In this case, if it wasn't MS silently changing something, the relationship properties may have changed, for example, or a relationship was inappropriately auto-detected (can you absolutely prove this didn't happen?)

Comment: I know it sounds weird, but I am the only admin of this report and I did not touch it for several weeks. And one day I got the messages, that the people with two roles do not have access anymore :/ 
Anyway, I am already working on fixing it by changing the model without m:n relationships and optimize it on different aspects. Would be interesting what happend anyway.

Comment: Was there a change in representatives and their regions? Maybe that caused RLS to fail. Just a wild thought however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a change that broke this around the December 2021 update.

**Source (See response from v-jayw-msf):** https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Dashboard-with-multiple-RLS-roles-work-in-My-Workspace-but-fails/m-p/2264783#U2264783

This was not resolved as of 2/7/2022, but two workarounds have been provided in the Microsoft documentation.

**Source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls#issue-multiple-roles-and-limited-relationships